# JS код перевести в php переменную

Tags: javascript, php

Есть вот такой скрипт статистики:

```
if(window.location.href.toString().indexOf('?page=evpl-sessions') > -1){
    var events = [];
 
    $('.wp-list-table td span.session-details a').each(function(){
      var event_id = $(this).data('event_id');
      if(events.indexOf(event_id) == -1){
        events.push($(this).data('event_id'));
      }
    });
 
    var events_data = 'events=' + events.join() + '&&action=otvazhnii_get_stats';
    var trid;
 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: events_data,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: ajaxurl,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
 
        $.each(data, function(event_id, event){
          $.each(event, function(time, tickets){
            var seats_checked = 0,
                amount_paid_checked = 0,
                orders_checked = 0;
 
            $('.wp-list-table td span.session-details a').each(function(){
              if($(this).data('event_id') == event_id){
                trid = $(this).parents('tr');
 
                if($(trid).find('td.event_date').text() == tickets['date']){
                  $.each(tickets, function(price, places){
                    if(!isNaN(price)){
                      var total = parseInt(price) * parseInt(places);
                      var html = places + ' шт. по ' + price + ' руб., всего ' + total.toString() + ' руб.';
                      $(trid).find('td.places_amount').children('.stats').append('<div class="ffffffff">' + html + '</div>');
                      amount_paid_checked += total;
                      seats_checked += parseInt(places);
                    }else if(price == 'orders_checked'){
                      orders_checked = parseInt(places);
                    }
                  });
 
                  // в конце сводить вместе цены и места
                  $(trid).find('td.orders_amount').children('.plus').text('Оплаченных заказов: ' + orders_checked);
                  if(parseInt($(trid).find('td.orders_amount').children('.total').data('value')) != orders_checked){
                    $(trid).find('td.orders_amount').children('.plus, .total');
                  }
                  $(trid).find('td.places_amount').children('.plus').text('Оплаченных мест: ' + seats_checked);
                  if(parseInt($(trid).find('td.places_amount').children('.total').data('value')) != seats_checked){
                    $(trid).find('td.places_amount').children('.plus, .total');
                  }else{
                    $(trid).find('td.places_amount').children('.plus, .total');
                  }
 
                  $(trid).find('td.sum_prices').children('.plus').text('Сумма оплаченных билетов: ' + amount_paid_checked + ' рублей');
                  if(parseInt($(trid).find('td.sum_prices').children('.total').data('value')) != amount_paid_checked){
                    $(trid).find('td.sum_prices').children('.plus, .total');
                  }else{
                    $(trid).find('td.sum_prices').children('.plus, .total');
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
 
 
      }, error: function(err1, err2, err3){
        out('Ошибка! ' + err3.toString());
      }
    });
```

php вывод:

```
switch( $column_name ) {
  case 'event_id':
    return 'Заказ №'.$item->event_id;
        
  case 'event_date':
    return $item->event_date;
  //   $newDate = date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($item->event_date));
  //   $newDate;
        
  case 'orders_amount':
    return '<div class="stats-order" data-value="' . $item->orders_amount . '">Всего заказов <b>' . $item->orders_amount . '</b> из них:</div>'
          . '<div class="plus"></div>'
          . '<div class="stats-order">Заказов по промокоду: <b>'. $stats_order_promo_number .'</b></div>'
          . '<div class="stats-order">Пригласительных: <b>'. $order_invitation_summa_ .'</b></div>';
        
  case 'places_amount':
    return '<div class="stats-order" data-value="' . $item->places_amount . '">Всего мест <b>' . $item->places_amount . '</b> из них:</div>'
         . '<div class="plus stats-order"></div>'
         . '<div class="stats stats-order"></div>'
         . '<div class="stats-order">По промокоду: <b>'.$stats_order_promo_place.' </b></div>';
        
  case 'sum_prices':
    return '<div class="stats-order">Поступило в банк: <b>'.$count.'</b> рублей из них:</div>'
         . '<div class="plus"></div>'
         . '<div class="stats-order">Сумма сервисного сбора: <b> ### </b> рублей</div>'
         . '<div class="stats-order">Доплаты к промокоду: <b>'.$stats_order_promo_payment.'</b> рублей</div>'
         . '<div class="stats-order">Сумма пригласительных: <b>'.$stats_order_invitation_summas.'</b> рублей</div>';
 
  default:
    return print_r( $item, true ) ;
}
```

Интересует часть js кода с суммой оплаченных заказов, как его сделать в php переменную, чтобы с этой php переменной можно было в дальнейшем работать.

Comment: PHP код выполняется на сервере. Производятся все вычисления, формируется страница и отправляется пользователю. Далее, уже на клиентской машине выполняется js код и сервер про эти вычисления не знает. Нужно делать форму отправки данных на сервер.

Comment: то есть данных js код никак не считает эту статистику? А что он тогда выполняет?